# Arguments passed by reference error

Tags: c++, kinect, ros

I have 2 main source files. I need to have 2 variables from source 1 to be passed to source 2.

The variables will grab the values that I need from a kinect (x-coordinates, y-coordinates). The variables with the ever-changing values from the kinect. They will be used on source code 2 to publish the values as a ROS marker in rviz.

I am planning to use a function with Arguments passed by reference. Grab the values from kinect in source 1 and pass them to the function that will be defined in source 2.

I could not pass the values to the function in source code 1.

Below shown the part of my code where I'm trying to pass the value into m2fun() which I declared in source 1.cpp.

Any form of help will be greatly appreciated !

P.S: I have tried declaring extern variables y,z and hoping to get the values from source1 and link it to source 2 but it does not work.. I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/functions2/) for the arguments passed by reference.

source1.cpp

```
float y1,z1,y,z; << global variable

float m2fun(float& y,float& z); 

defined y = (value from kinect);
defined z = (another value from kinect);
```

//the values from kinect are from a static function();

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float y1 = y;
    float z1 = z;
    m2fun(y1,z1);

}
```

and below are the errors after compiling..

```
/home/i2r/catkin_ws/src/kinect2_tracker/src/kinect2_tracker_node.cpp:65:7: error: ‘float y1’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
float y1,z1,y,z;

   ^
```

In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,

```
             from /usr/include/stdlib.h:24,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/platform.h:53,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:53,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
             from /home/i2r/catkin_ws/src/kinect2_tracker/src/../include/kinect2_tracker.hpp:17,
             from /home/i2r/catkin_ws/src/kinect2_tracker/src/kinect2_tracker_node.cpp:8:

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:241:1: error: previous     declaration of ‘double y1(double)’
 __MATHCALL (y1,, (_Mdouble_));

^
make[2]: *** [kinect2_tracker/CMakeFiles/kinect2_tracker_node.dir/src/kinect2_tracker_node.cpp.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [kinect2_tracker/CMakeFiles/kinect2_tracker_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j32 -l32" failed
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here. It's especially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Can't help you if your code does not even work. There is no y and z. Also, you realize that global variables are a big no-go, right?

Comment: @Aziuth 
There are no specific value i assign to y and z, i declare a variable ( for eg. a ) to grab a set of values from my kinect , then i pass on the values from a to y ( y = a; ). The reason i declare global variables because in my current code , most of the functions are static functions. Or if there are any workaround to get a value out from a static function, please kindly advice me !

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by "get a value out from a static function"? You simply call it and take the returned value? Can you show me an example of one of your static functions?

Comment: @Aziuth 
i want to get the y and z values from this static function below..

   `void SampleViewer::glutDisplay()
    {

    SampleViewer::ms_self->Display();
    t = (rjoint2_z - rjoint1_z)/(-rjoint1_z);
    intersect_kx = (rjoint1_x + t*(rjoint2_x - rjoint1_x))/1000;
    intersect_ky = (rjoint1_y + t*(rjoint2_y - rjoint1_y))/1000;
    intersect_py = -intersect_kx;
    intersect_pz = intersect_ky - 1.025;
    y = intersect_py;
    z = intersect_pz;
 
    }`

Comment: Why not `struct Coordinates {int x, int y, Coordinates(...)}; Coordinates SampleViewer::glutDisplay(){ ... `  or `SampleViewer::glutDisplay(int& x, int& y){...`?

Comment: @Aziuth
The rjoint values are extracted from another static function referred below..

`void DrawSkeleton(nite::UserTracker* pUserTracker, const nite::UserData& userData)
{
 rjoint2_x = userData.getSkeleton().getJoint(nite::JOINT_RIGHT_HAND).getPosition().x;
 rjoint1_x = userData.getSkeleton().getJoint(nite::JOINT_RIGHT_SHOULDER).getPosition().x;

}`

Comment: @Aziuth
sorry im abit new to c++ .. can i know what is struct used for ? And how does it work ?

Comment: struct is simply a data holder. Technically, it works like a class, only that members are public by default. Here I simply created something that could be used as a return value. Since C++ can't return two values (like for example Matlab could), I bundled them in one. Works like `Coordinate c; c.x = 5; c.y = 10;`. Usually, you use a struct when you want a pure data holder, which an actual class should not be.

Comment: @Aziuth i don't really understand struct Coordinates {int x, int y, Coordinates(...)}; Why mention Coordinates twice for this ? for struct Coordinates i understand, but why Coordinates(...) is what i don't really get. i learn about struct here cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures .I also have difficulty understanding what Coordinates SampleViewer::glutDisplay(){ ... or SampleViewer::glutDisplay(int& x, int& y){... actually meant.. or how does it function ?

Comment: Ah, the dots represent arguments, haven't been thorough here, thought that struct was known. In full it would be `struct Coordinates {int x, int y, Coordinates(const int _x, const int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {} }`  - structures use constructors.

Comment: @Aziuth
if i just followed as written , `struct Coordinates{ int x, int y, Coordinates(const int _x, const int_y) :x(_x), y(_y) {} };`  , i get error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
 struct Coordinates{ int x, int y, Coordinates(const int _x, const int_y) :x(_x), y(_y) {} }
                            ^

Comment: @Aziuth The arrow is pointed right below int y , right after the `{ int x, `

Comment: My bad, typed the comment far too fast, right code is `struct Coordinates{ int x; int y; Coordinates(const int _x, const int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {} };`. But realize that this is just an example to illustrate how to structurize something. I thought that you were familiar with structures - if you are not, don't copy my code but search for a tutorial on structs. I assumed that since you worked with stuff like that in the question, you'd do. Question, if you are not familiar with struct, are you familiar with classes?

Comment: @Aziuth 
i've seen some videos on c++ classes, although its just some basic class illustration.

Comment: Read the basic tutorials. Classes are basically the core of C++. When you do something, you do it in classes. Important code is to be within some class method.

Answer (score 0):

Change your main function as following.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //You are trying to redefine the variables z1 and y1
    y1 = y; 
    z1 = z;`enter code here`
    m2fun(y1,z1);
}
```

Comment: i changed as followed but it still game me errors when compiled..

But the float y1 remains unsolved, as well as previous declaration of ‘double y1(double)’
 __MATHCALL (y1,, (_Mdouble_));

and theres  error: assignment of function ‘double y1(double)’
  y1 = y;
       ^
followed by error: cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘double(double)throw ()’ in assignment , error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘float&’ from an rvalue of type ‘double (*)(double)throw ()’
  m2fun(y1,z1);
             ^
lastly... error: in passing argument 1